# How to implement a Scheme interpreter without recursion?

Tags: scheme, interpreter

I tried to design a Scheme interpreter which is non-recursive, using a stack and pointer to walk on the AST and evaluate.

Things are just fine if I only need to tackle with pure procedure calls. However, once macros comes, the irregular syntax makes it hard to write a non-recursive routine. (because of the mixture of different semantics) What's worse, the non-recursive approach seemingly becomes incredibly complex when taking **built-in macros (like if, conf let, etc.)** into account.

Any good suggestions on implementing a non-recursive interpreter? Or any materials on that? I've googled hard but found nothing.

And, I wonder whether the mainstream Scheme interpreters use this kind of approach. Maybe I can just write in recursion and it won't be blamed.

Comment: Have to different phases of your interpreter, expand the macros and then eval

Comment: @jozefg You mean that there aren't actual evalution operations in macro? How about builtin macros like if, let, cond, etc.

Comment: If you only implement `syntax-rules` then yes, you can sneak by with simple, dumb, pattern expansion. `syntax-case` supports arbitrary scheme so you'd need to run your interpreter in 2 phases

Comment: Also, either if or cond is a macro. Not both. There needs to be at least 1 form of conditional evaluation.

Comment: @jozefg But in `guile`, it says they're both built-in. What's going on? Besides, how about `let`, I find it hard to put this syntax into existing code.

Comment: @ymfoi `let` is a macro too. An expression like `(let ((foo 42) (bar 10)) (+ foo bar))` expands to `((lambda (foo bar) (+ foo bar)) 42 10)`.

Comment: They can be both built-in. They cannot both be macros.

Comment: OK I cracked and posted answer to get this out of comment land

Comment: Why do you think you would be 'blamed' for 'writing in recursion?'

Comment: @GoZoner I guess the recursion depth in the language interpreted should not be limited by the constraint brought by interpreter.

Comment: @jozefg all we really need is branching (can be strict) and goto (continuations). any non-strict operator could be defined as a macro then. Of course this strict branching primitive would become available  in such an implementation, and it's not in the specs. So by Occam's Razor it's not advisable, but it *is* possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vanilla r5rs scheme, macros are just a DSL for rearranging the AST. They operate on a purely syntactic level and should be separate from the interpreter.

In R6RS or CL or whatever, macros can actually do computations which means they need 2 runs of the interpreter, one to expand macros and one to evaluate the resulting AST.

For example given this code

```
 (let ((x 5))
   (if (= x 5)
       (display "Woohoo")
       (error)))
```

You should run a macro expander over it in the first phase leaving the AST

```
 ((lambda (x)
    (cond
      ((= x 5) (display "Woohoo"))
      (else (error)))) 5)
```

Doing this should evaluate **no code**. Merely rearrange the AST. Then when your interpreter runs over it, it shouldn't even have to know that macros exist.

So your final scheme interpreter should look like this

```
Parse File
   |
   |
   |
Expand All Macros
   |
   |
   |
Optimize/Black Magic
   |
   |
   |
Optional ByteCode compilation or similar IL
   |
   |
Evaluate
   |
   |
Profit
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that the interpreter like `guile` implements `let` as directly as `if` instead of defining it as a macro?

Comment: @ymfoi Sure. You could, but there's no need to. You'll want to make function calls dirt cheap anyways since that's pretty much all scheme is

Comment: How about the convention? (This is my first attempt on writing an interpreter, so don't know much of it.) And how about the efficiency?

Comment: @ymfoi Ideally, you want as few builtins as possible, while still maintaining reasonable performance. Since `let` is easily defined as a `lambda` construction-and-call, it seems counterproductive to make it a special case, unless your lambdas are heavyweight, in which case you have bigger problems.

Comment: @ymfoi the only reason for let to be built in is for a typechecker. Scheme is dynamically typed so you just end up with a more complex interpreter for no gain

Comment: @jozefg I'm not sure how a builtin `let` allows any greater amount of typechecking than is already enabled by its expanded form.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young In a strongly typed functional language there is a difference between let and lambda, but only then. It's part of the HM algorithm, see Let-generalization

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young The key difference is that `\x : T. y` `T` is a monotype but a let can bind polymorphically.

Comment: @jozefg First hit when searching for "let generalization": [Let Should Not Be Generalised](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/constraints/let-gen.pdf), coauthored by Simon Peyton Jones. ;-)

Comment: @jozefg One last question. Can I regard the magic `if` syntax as a procedure that use a less-magic `if2` `(define if (lambda (exp a b) ((if2 (lambda () a) (lambda () b)))))`? (`if2` doesn't guarantee only one of expressions `a` and `b` will be evaluated)

Comment: @jozefg Is that efficient enough? I'll use this if it's okay because it can eliminate lots of complexity.

Comment: @ymfoi You eval arguments before function application. `if` **cannot** be a normal scheme function.

Comment: @jozefg What if I use `lambda` to postpone the evaluation? Check my code above.

Comment: I checked your code above, if you treat if like a function you apply some function to 3 arguments. Those arguments are evaluated **on application of the function**. Doesn't matter what the heck you do inside the function, they're already evaluated.

Comment: @ymfoi That's pretty much what it means to be an applicative language. Any other behavior and you don't have Scheme anymore

Comment: @jozefg Oh I didn't notice the parameter list, thanks. Are there any other syntax having this kind of unique feature? Or can I assert that there' only three primitive things in Scheme at all: `define` `lambda` and `if`?

Comment: Anything that short circuits and doesn't eval all it's args necessarily is a macro. Just work on that principle, or breaks the syntax of the language (eg cond)

Comment: @jozefg Yeah, I know. But `if` is special, isn't it? Others can be obtained by substitution. Can I have that assertion?

Comment: `if` `lambda` `define` are your basic kernel. Other things like `car` and `cdr` are also primitiv

Answer (score 4):

Whle researching for my Scheme compiler I have read lots of papers about all sorts of old problems related to compilation. Related to macros and @jozefg's nice illustration of separating actual interpreting and macro espansions that I found was [Alexpander](http://petrofsky.org/src/alexpander.scm), written by Al Petrofsky. He has also written [Eval in one define](http://petrofsky.org/src/eiod.scm),  which is a nice interpreter with syntax-rules.

I have previously written a [Lisp1 interpreter that runs on Brainf*ck](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/). It had a stack with alternating cell addresses to set-car! the result and the expression to be evaluated.

Eval is something like this:

```
(pop_stack register1) ; expression
(while-not-zero register1
   ... do computation
   (pop_stack register2) ; return address
   (open-cons register2) ; opens location
   (set-car register1)   ; sets value 
   (pop_stack register1)) ; next job
```

It supports standard McCharty LISP1 stuff, including macros (flambda).

A simple expression like (cons 'a 'b) used 6 rounds in the while loop, like this:

1. (cons 'a 'b)
2. cons => procedure:cons
3. (pre-apply procedure:cons 'a 'b)
4. 'a => a
5. 'b => b
6. (apply procedure:cons 'a 'b)

Because of this i could rename every keyword. Eg. this works:

```
(let ((mylambda lambda))
   (mylambda (x) (cons '1 x)))
```